# Multiple feedback band-pass filter issue in LT Spice

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, ltspice, active-filter, band-pass

For a school project, we are tasked to make a band pass filter with a center frequency of 1000 kHz, 1 MHz. Everything works fine below 1.1 MHz. In the picture below, a sine wave with a frequency of 1.4M Hz is the input (green graph) and the output (blue graph) is not normal at all. If I change the input frequency to 700 kHz, the output is what I expect it to be. I'm not sure what the issue is, maybe the op-amp.

[image: 1.4Mhz]

[image: 700kHz]

Comment: Don't use node numbers because nobody but you understands which nodes they are on the circuit. Name your nodes and display named-node signals. Also link to the data sheet of the op-amp. Your first diagram cuts-off the top of the circuit making it guesswork.

Comment: Is \$R_2\$ supposed to be 84 Ohms?

Comment: Also, what do you think \$f_0\$ is for this multifeedback? (Just want to check to see if you've done the calcs.)

Comment: Please note that for this circuit alternative you cannot select Q and the midband gain independently